# Replacement window spring won't raise

Tags: windows, replacement

Old house with double-glazed replacement window. I had to have one of the glass panes replaced and was able to easily tilt in the window and remove the lower unit.  Upon replacement, the window goes right in, I cannot slide it down and when I slide it up, it pulls out of the support springs in both tracks.  I feel as though something is holding the spring in the current position. As if it is locked there. What am I missing?

Comment: What does "old" mean? What type or brand window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking closer at the window it appears the posts that engage the spring supports are keyed and when you rotate the window back in place the spring support is unlocked.  Of course on my windows the locks are going bad...

Comment: If you could post a picture of the window hardware, particularly where the lower window corners engage the sash balance/support spring, we all would have an easier time giving advice.

Comment: Was this posted as an answer or a clarifying comment?